# how to publish multiple rest endpoints with same base address?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, osgi, restful-url

first our scenario:

we have an OSGI environment, where several bundles publish their own rest endpoint, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/cars
http://localhost:8080/api/food
http://localhost:8080/api/toys
```

This was done using JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create() method, with address being the ones listed above.

Now we need to add a tenant id to the users requests (not user auth, which is different, as users may be part of several tenants). URLs should look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/tenant/{tenantid}/cars
http://localhost:8080/api/tenant/{tenantid}/food 
http://localhost:8080/api/tenant/{tenantid}/toys
```

I tried two approaches to achieve this now:

1. Add tenant-id to address of service (`http://localhost:8080/api/tenant/{tenantid}`) - **Result**: I could access my service under the given URL, but I couldn't fill any data for tenantid but had to type {tenantid} in the URL, which is not how I need to use it.
2. Publish all three services under the same URL (`http://localhost:8080/api`) moving the tenant-part to the @Path annotation of each api class - **Result**: Exception, that address was already taken by other endpoint

Does anyone have an idea, how this can be done properly? I know that the ServiceBean can take an array of implementors as an argument instead of a single class, but this is not an option, as the bundles load separately and I had some dependency issues, when I tried make this "all in one".

As a sidenote: I know, we could put tenant id in a header, but typically tenant info is somewhere in a URL (host or path) and we wanna go with this "common" style instead of adding a custom header, though implementation of header style would be much easier (already got it to work).

Any ideas would help.
Thanks,
Kay

Comment: any more ideas? we're about to do it using query params, which is what we were trying to avoid...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
@Path("/tenants")
public class TenantResource{

    @Path("/{tenantId}/cars")
    @Get
    public List<Car> getTenantCars(@PathParam("tenantId") long tenantId){...}

    @Path("/{tenantId}/food")
    @Get
    public Food getTenantFood(@PathParam("tenantId") long tenantId){...}

    @Path("/{tenantId}/toys")
    @Get
    public List<Toy> getTenantToys(@PathParam("tenantId") long tenantId){...}
}
```

If you have URLs such as tenants/{tenantid}/cars then this usually means "the cars of the tenant with id = tenantid".

"cars" is a property of the "tenant" resource and thus should be in the same resource. 
I think it might be hard to modularize properties of a resource/ object.

But you could consider a "car" resource and query the resource like: /cars?tenantid={tenantid}

```
@Path("/cars")
public class CarResource{

    @Get
    public List<Car> getCarsByTenantId(@QueryParam("tenantId") long tenantId){...}

}
```

or similar.

Comment: I know these solutions would work, but my endpoints were just some examples and "cars" is the root of CRUD ops as well as more detailed info 
 - something like /cars/sensors/temperature/ or /cars/tires/pressure - hanging all this stuff under "/tenants"would blow up your proposed TenantResource class to like 60+ methods (as opposed to for each of the 3 single Resource Classes...

As for the query param: As I said there's also CRUD ops, including POST, DELETE and PUT, thus query params are not an option.